# template method of non-template class

Tags: c++, templates

I was sure that template class member of non-template should always have explicit specialization for all types with which it is instantiated. Isn't that true?

However, the following code works fine

```
class C
{
public:
template <class T>
int tfunc(T t) { T t2(t); }
}

int main()
{
  C c;
  c.tfunc((float)1);
}
```

Comment: "...should always have explicit specialization" --- why do you think so? I think it is in no way different from a simple free-standing template functon, shich also does not require explicit specialization.

Comment: Just to say it, you don't have to cast 1 to float you can use 1.0f

Comment: @Petr Because something very similiar was in my practice, but obviously I've remembered it incorrectly. Do you know any special cases when you HAVE to specialize all types with which you instantiate a template?

Comment: @VladimirLenin, I can think only of a case when you do not put the template definitions into the header file.

Comment: I think it is the case, but why it differs? Could you advice a good article on this ...

Answer (score 1):

Template methods of non-template classes are no different to any other template functions and do not require any specializations to work so your code is fine.